# Multiple Bluetooth devices on App Inventor

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth, app-inventor

Is it possible to use MIT App Inventor 2 to connect my phone to two bluetooth devices? I need to connect to another phone and an Arduino(3 devices in total). How could I do that?

Comment: sure, that's possible. A simple Google search would give you some examples, for example the [Bluetooth chat example](https://puravidaapps.com/btchat.php)...

Comment: Thanks, but I've already searched, the link you pointed only explains how to use bluetooth between two devices, see "The example only works to send messages between 2 devices." I need to connect my phone to other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

As you already found out, a `bluetooth` component in **App Inventor** can only connect 2 devices.

In your case, just use 2 bluetooth components: `component1` to connect to another phone and `component2` to connect to an Arduino.

[See also the documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/connectivity.html#BluetoothClient)